# Why is this partial call not passing its locals values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried the following code to render a partial

```
= render partial: 'movie_same', locals: { current: @movie }, collection: @movie.dvd.movies.order('scene')
```

But I get this error

```
NameError in Movies#show
Showing /Users/user/app/views/movies/_movie_same.html.haml where line #1 raised:
undefined local variable or method `locals' for #<#<Class:0x007fe713ba90a8>:0x007fe710f79a00>
```

The mention in the render file is just to `locals[:current]`.

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `locals[:current]` in the partial. You just need to use `current` as `:locals` will set it as local variable in the target partial. so it will be just

`current`

This is what is said from the [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/PartialRenderer)

> would provide the @buyer object to the partial, available under the
>   local variable account

```
<%= render :partial => "account", :locals => { :account => @buyer } %>
```